# syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'iDlg'

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I am trying to get a dialog box [import] to launch from another dialog box [baseline].
I am including the required ".h" files however I am simply not able to create an instance of the import class. The error I get is this:

```
Error   1   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'iDlg'    h:\shaunak\projects\sar_ccd\sar_ccd\baseline.h  202 1   Sar_CCD
```

The line of code that causes this [baseline.h]:

```
#include "Markup.h" 
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include "baseline_func.h"
#include "resource.h"
#include "Functions.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Sar_CCDDoc.h"
#include "Sar_CCDView.h"
#include <vector>
#include "MemAlloc.h"
#include "ReadFiles.h"
#include<vector>
#include<map>
#include "afxwin.h"
#include "import.h"
#include "Geocode.h"




**<SNIP: Taking out the irrelevant lines>**

     afx_msg void OnDestroy();
     virtual void PostNcDestroy();
     afx_msg void OnBnClickedNxtBase();
     CButton nextBaseline;


    import iDlg;               //doesnt work!
    CGeocoding cx;             //works!!!
};
```

However, if I create and instance of another class [Geocoding] using the same sysntax like so, it works fine:

```
#include "Geocoding.h"
CGeocoding cx;
```

Please help me figure out why.

Full code:

baseline.h: http://freetexthost.com/on06wref6c
import.h: http://freetexthost.com/x4e4dkwrve

Comment: What is `import iDlg;` actually? Is import a class of yours?

Comment: Is `import` something you created? Or is it documented somewhere? (We have no idea what this code is supposed to do unless you tell us.)

Comment: Btw, `
**<SNIP: Taking out the irrelevant lines>**
` looks funny after all those #includes and #defines :P

Comment: Sorry about the lack of detail, import is the name of a class -> created in import.cpp. "import" is a class, just like "CGeocoding" is. I am really sorry about not being clear. This is the first time I am posting a question.

Comment: Since the compiler can't see `import.cpp` while it's compiling this code, it can't make sense of that statement. If `import.h` was supposed to make this work, then the problem is likely in that file.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, maybe OP just mixes "declaration" and "implementation", that's not a big deal in that case... But you have a point ofc.

Comment: import.h -> http://freetexthost.com/x4e4dkwrve - this file is included in other places as well. It doesnt cause errors

Comment: Triple-check that you don't have some other file called `import.h` (or `Import.h` since your platform is case-insensitive) that might be getting included instead of the one you expect. Another possibility is that some header you include later has a `#define import __declspec(dllimport)` that's breaking things.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I checked thoroughly, only one import.h and import.cpp, no defines.

Comment: @eternalDreamer, that's pretty weird, based on the code you provided, it _should_ work

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall - I rechecked all that I knew about classes! It simply refuses to work. I found a workaround, by sending a message to the parent window and using a pointer to initialize the dialog box. I still have no idea what's happened here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio there is a keyword import or #import rather used to import a COM DLL and is used for other things as well. I guess you are experiencing a name collision there.

In order to get around it place your class import in a `namespace`

```
import.h

namespace myimport
{
  class import : public CDialog { 
  ...
  };
};

import.cpp

namespace myimport
{
  ...
};
```

then when you use it

```
myimport::import iDlg;
```

that should solve the issue, although renaming it to something else than "import" would be the better way to go.

Comment: Is there any simple way to refactor the class?

Comment: I spent a bit of time downloading tools to rename this but to no avail. :( It still does not work. And the namespace will just get messy as the class is used all over the project. Il focus on this later.

Answer (score 0):

`import` is not a keyword or type in C++. Therefore you get a syntax error because the compiler doesn't recognize `import`.

To create an instance of another class you have to properly declare it, e.g.:

```
class baseline : public CDialog
{
    // ...

    CDialog *iDlg;  // Pointer to imported dialog
};
```

Remember to initialize the pointer to the actual dialog.

Comment: How about this: `struct import{...}; import iDlg;`?

Comment: I did not intend to use "import" as a keyword. "import" is a name of a class that inherits from CDialog, just like "CGeocoding". {I am really sorry if I am not clear enough}

Comment: but in any case naming a class `import` is a bad idea

Comment: @andrew - the girl who was working on this project before me did. And I cant find anyway to "refactor" it (as you can in C#)